# ...(,) просто опираясь

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

`Мне, честно, делать наращения удобней(,) просто опираясь на то, согласная или гласная перед последней буквой.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет причин не ставить запятую:

*Мне, честно, делать наращения удобней (как?), **просто опираясь на то,** согласная или гласная перед последней буквой.*

Деепричастный оборот обособляется, здесь нет перехода деепричастия **в наречие**.  Придаточное входит в состав оборота.

Но это **грамматическая** запятая, так как произношение практически без паузы.

**Пример:** *Совет этот мы дали вам, **опираясь** на собственный опыт.*